# Angular 2 Pass id from ngFor to a control

Tags: angular

I am dynamically creating  dropdowns from a service.

I Need help to capture a value and pass it a service and need help to capture what was selected for example:  **Feb** from month dropdown and **2017** from year dropdown.

tab.component.service,  GetDropdownControls WILL bring back  how many dropdowns i need for this tab as well as the label. Example:

GetDropdownControls( this is what I have now)

```
{"result":[
   {
     "DropDownID":1,
     "DropDownTitle":"Month"

   },
   {
     "DropDownID":2,
     "DropDownTitle":"Year"
   }
 ]
}
```

the output will be:

> Month : Dropdown
>
> Year  : Dropdown

This  is what is needed (One control looks like this. Note: my sub-array might be formatted incorrectly):

```
controls = {
  DropDownID":1,
  DropDownTitle":Month
  selectArray: [ // stuff that would be placed in the select
   {
     ID: 1,
     value: January,
     ID: 2,
     value: feb,
     ID: 3,
     value: March,
     ID: 4,
     value: April,
     etc...


   }  
  ] 
}
```

GetDropdownControlValues Method will return the values for the dropwdown for example:
if "DropDownID":1 is passed to this method , Will get January, Feb,March, April,etc which they will be bind to (Month's Dropdown list)

tab.component

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() tabTitle: string;

    tabControls: ITabControls[];
    tabControlValues: ITabControlValues[];


    getDropdownControlValues(drodownID: number) {
        this._tabService.GetrodownControlValues(drodownID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tabControlValues = data.result
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this._tabService.GetControls(1)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.tabControls = data.result
    //need to call getDropdownControlValues for every DropdownID
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        console.log('tab Service  ' + this.tabControls);


    }

}
```

tab.ts

```
export interface ITabdrodownControls {
    DropDownID: number;
    DropDownTitle: string;

}

export interface ITabControlValues {

    ID: number;
    Value: string;



}
```

tab.component.html, I am unable to pass the DropDownID from ngFor to "option" . once the DropDownID  is passed I need to go back to tab.component to call a service ( GetDropdownControlValues) that will return id and text to bind  as well as a change event to capture what id of what dropwdown was selected?

```
 <div class="row  left" *ngFor='let controls of tabControls'>
     <div class="col-md-3 text-left" style="border:1px dotted">
         {{controls.DropDownTitle}}
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
         <select>
             <option //need to pass control.DropDownID and ngfor to bind the values></option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

current output:

[image]

Comment: Could you cut away the noise and just present the issue at hand. Where does this value reside, where do you want to pass it and how you have tried to pass it. There's lots of code that does not seem to relate to this at all, please just present the essential. Why do you have the select inside your iteration? The content is not a subarray of tabscontrols if I understand correctly? Seems confusing.

Comment: I re-arranged my code , the value reside in tab.component.html. I have the select inside the iteration because it needs the ID which will call a service for binding. I need to pass {{controls.DropDownID}} to the <option> as well as ngFor inside <option>. I hope this cleared things out!

Comment: Okay, at least that cleared things out, meaning that there is indeed nested data that needs to be iterated in the dropdown :) Thanks. This is essential info, needed in question, so that we do not get confused like I did :D

Comment: Still is confusing... please, no offense, but I wrote a little story for you to help you make your question clearer ;) Check the app.ts file. As said, no offense, just want to help you :) https://plnkr.co/edit/Gilp44S8FcYr3IZiqeNg

Comment: None taken, Thanks for your help. You help me to make my current question and future questions  clearer for everyone to understand. Really appreciate your help. I edited my code

Comment: **"This is what is neededed. One control looks like this"**. So is this something you *need* or do you have it? So currently you have nothing in your select, or? So do you want to push an array to your current controls??

Comment: this what i need, i don't have anything in the select. and yes I want to push an array to my current control. I don't have it because I can't figure out how to construct it.

Comment: I see, now I get it :) But is there a reason why e.g the month control wouldn't have the values already set in the backend? That would make more sense, I mean, months are months, they do not change, so why go to lots of trouble to put months in an existing object in the frontend??

Comment: month is just one control and just trying to make things consistent as the dropdown might contain only three months not all  months will be listed., I will have more dropdowns which values  will be inserted by another admin application into a database.

Comment: Ah okay, now it starts to make sense ;)